# Mod_Rewrite Virtual Directory Issues

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was wondering how I would rewrite this:

```
https://www.johndong.net/Programs/Files/b85c73b3ee77c9762161edf89b63041217acccdc
```

to this:

```
https://www.johndong.net/Programs/Files/view.php?file=b85c73b3ee77c9762161edf89b63041217acccdc
```

This is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule https://www.johndong.net/Programs/Files/(.*) https://www.johndong.net/Programs/Files/view.php?file=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteRule` only matches `REQUEST_URI` (without domain name). Use this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^(Programs/Files)/([^./]+)/?$ /$1/view.php?file=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: And that .htaccess file should go in: /Programs/Files/ right?

Comment: No it should be in DOCUMENT_ROOT which seems to be a level above `/Programs/` in your case.

Comment: That works, thanks :D
Also, how would I do
http://www.gooby.co/(random id)
to
http://www.gooby.co/index.php?id=(random id)
http://www.gooby.co/(random id)